# Why does a string read from stdin never match the strings I compare it to?

Tags: rust

I am trying to `match` on a user-supplied string with this code:

```
use std::io;

fn main() {
    let mut input = String::new();

    io::stdin().read_line(&mut input).expect("Failed to read line.");

    match input.as_ref(){
        "test" => println!("That was test"),
        _ => print!("Something's wrong"),
    }
}
```

However, this code always prints "Something's wrong", even when I enter "test". How can I make this work as intended?

Comment: "this isn't working" is not a problem description. Are you getting errors? Which ones? Are you getting unexpected output? Which one did you expect?

Comment: try `input.trim().as_ref()` to get rid of the tailing newline

Comment: Yes, my problem is unexpected output. this code not working as i wanted. Always giving me "Somethings wrong"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This doesn't match `"test"` even if (it looks like) you enter `"test"` because you're also inputting a new line by hitting Enter, so `input` will actually contain `"test\n"`.

You can solve this by removing the trailing newline using [`trim_end`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html#method.trim_end):

```
match input.trim_end() {
    "test" => println!("Great!"),
    _ => println!("Too bad")
}
```

This won't modify the original string, though.

Comment: Thanks sir. This is solving my problem.